# Get Data if exists, If not Hide [CMB2]

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress CMS and CMB2 plugin for creating metaboxes and custom fields.So I'm trying to make on front end stuff like this:

IF my_custom_text_field have something inside(filled in) - then get this data, but if it is empty show some text. I'm using cmb2 custom metabox plugin to make custom metaboxes and fields. I have first part

```
    <?php $seo_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'seo_general_title', true );  echo esc_html( $seo_title );?>
```

but how to get my custom text if this field is empty i don't know.
there was topic with the same problem but it not works for me `https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/cmb2-display-group-field-meta-data-if-exists-if-empty-display-default-text/`
 Maybe someone can help? thanks.

Comment: please give more details such as the cms you are using ( i guess this is wordpress ) , take a look here [mcve] to clarify your question

Comment: updated, is it enough? I think it is like if statement for wordpress, but dont know how to detect if my cmb2 field is empty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer should help you :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56597/if-get-post-meta-is-empty-do-something

```
  <?php $seo_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'seo_general_title', true ); 
  if ( !empty($seo_title)){
     echo $seo_title;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: i cant add thumb up my reputation is not 15(( but really thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$seo_title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'seo_general_title', true);
$seo_title = (empty($seo_title)) ? "Default Value" : $seo_title;
echo $seo_title;
```

Or my preferred way since I think its readability is better (you define the value right in the IF clause, but be careful not to forget always put the assignment in the simple brackets).

```
<?php 
if (empty($seo_title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'seo_general_title', true)))
    $seo_title = "Default Value";
echo $seo_title;
```

Or the "most basic" way - but this expects that the `get_post_meta()` function always returns string value.

```
<?php
$seo_title = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'seo_general_title', true);
if ($seo_title == "") {
    $seo_title = "Default Value";
}
echo $value;
```

In the end it really pretty much depends on your taste.

Comment: i would say its even better to test the type too with '===' instead of '=='

Comment: Man it's Working! Can i just ask one more question. if data not exists I need to add some html or php  like  if string is empty then, and my html or php code... It will be the perfect answer but thank you so much for this too!

Comment: @nito well the question is, where would you like to put the "html or php code"... If you would like to put it in some specific place, then you would have to find a way to inject your "html or php" in that specific place. The way i look at it, your question is too generic right now.

Comment: @Charles-AntoineFournel In this case i am not sure if preventing data type conversion would affect the result anyhow, but you are right, that it is preferable practice.